# Получить адрес по координатам в Yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно по гео координатам получить адрес?

Т.е. есть координаты `30.524933, 50.447218` и нужно определить адрес или объект в данном случае - Украина, Киев, метро Крещатик. В гугле искал, все ищут наоборот.

Answer (score 9):

В яндекс картах есть как прямой так и обратный геокодер.
Прямой - это когда по адресу определяем координаты. 
Обратный, соответственно, обратно.
Вот ссылка на документацию: [geocode](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/geocode.xml).

Вот тут есть пример использования геокодера как прямого так и обатного [Примеры использования JavaScript API](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/examples/).

Еще примеры:

- [Помещение в balloonContentBody адреса](http://clubs.ya.ru/mapsapi/replies.xml?item_no=28399).
- [Используя обратное геокодирование, вывести полный адрес](http://clubs.ya.ru/mapsapi/replies.xml?item_no=28184).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?key=_здесь_нужен_АПИ_ключ_яндекс_"></script>
<script>
var map;
window.onload = function () {
    map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"));
    map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(35.01, 48.47), 13);
};

function go() {
var res, rescont='Адрес для точки (';
var lat=$("#ilat").val();
var lng=$("#ilng").val();
rescont+=lat+', '+lng+') это: ';
$.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/", 
        data:'geocode='+lng+','+lat+'&format=json&kind=house&results=2&key=_здесь_нужен_АПИ_ключ_яндекс_', 
        dataType:"JSON", timeout:30000, async:false,
        error: function(xhr) {
            rescont+='Ошибка геокодирования: '+xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText;
        },
        success: function(html) { 
            res=html;
            var geores=res.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember;
            if(geores.length>0) { 
                for(k=0;k<geores.length;k++) {
                    rescont+=geores[k].GeoObject.name+'; ';
                }
            } else {
                rescont+='нет данных';
            }                                    
       }
   });
    $('#iout').text(rescont);
map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(lng,lat));

}
</script>
```